# Disable click after one click in phaser.io using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, phaser-framework

I have three buttons like this:

```js
astroid: function() {

    astroid1 = this.add.button(15, 80, 'astroid1', this.astroid1Clicked, this);
    astroid2 = this.add.button(200, 10, 'astroid2', this.astroid2Clicked, this);
    astroid3 = this.add.button(400, 40, 'astroid3', this.astroid3Clicked, this);
    astroid4 = this.add.button(622, 90, 'astroid4', this.astroid4Clicked, this);
},
```

and have function for every button clicked:

```js
// Observing which asteroid is clicked and checking answer accordingly.
astroid1Clicked: function() {
    this.fire();

    //console.log(astroidContains[0]);
    // console.log(answear);
    //this.isCorrectAnswerHit(25, 100);
    if (astroidContains[0] == answear) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            //50 and 100 are the axis of astroid1
            Game.isCorrectAnswerHit(50, 100);
        }, 500);
    } else {
        this.isWrongAnswerHit();
    }
    allowClick = false;

    return false;
},

astroid2Clicked: function() {

    this.fire();

    //console.log(astroidContains[1]);
    //console.log(answear);
    if (astroidContains[1] == answear) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            Game.isCorrectAnswerHit(260, 10);
        }, 500);
    } else {
        this.isWrongAnswerHit();
    }

    allowClick = false;
    return false;
},

astroid3Clicked: function() {

    this.fire();

    //console.log(astroidContains[2]);
    //console.log(answear);
    if (astroidContains[2] == answear) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            Game.isCorrectAnswerHit(450, 40);
        }, 500);
    } else {
        this.isWrongAnswerHit();
    }
    allowClick = false;
    return false;
},

astroid4Clicked: function() {

    this.fire();
    //bullets.destroy();
    //console.log(astroidContains[3]);
    //console.log(answear);
    if (astroidContains[3] == answear) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            Game.isCorrectAnswerHit(620, 100);
        }, 500);
    } else {
        this.isWrongAnswerHit();
    }
    allowClick = false;
    return false;
},
```

I want as user clicks on one button that time all button will disable including button at which user click, all function will execute and then user can able to click on any button. Please help me I tried many thing but they are not working as I want, and it should be without jQuery.

Comment: I think you should first refactor your code - you have a lot of stuff that is repeating. You can for example move the answer checking logic to a separate function to which you pass the info you need as parameters.

Comment: I am repeating code because on every button click , i am performing different task , till the task is completed i want to prevent other or same button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use the flag you already have?

```
astroid4Clicked: function() {
  if (this.allowClick == true) {
  effect...
  this.allowClick = false;
  }
}
```

You then just have to decide when and in what circumstances you turn the flag back to true.

Better would be to check the flag in the update() function and not seperate in every function.

And yes you have a lot of code repeating ...

Comment: Thanks a lot you point out my silly mistake, now its working as i want.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use callbacks and not use the button class.

```
// Assuming `this` is the Phaser.State -- this is for callback safety
let thisState = this
var myFireFunction = function(event) {
    thisState.fire() 
    // ...

    // Add a delay timer (or, this could be a callback when the bullet strikes the target)
    var delay = thisState.game.time.create(true)
    delay.duration = 500 //milliseconds

    // add the callback to the input again
    delay.onComplete.addOnce( function() {
        thisState.input.onDown.addOnce(myFireFunction)
    })
    delay.start()
}

// Add the callback ONCE to the `onDown` event
this.input.onDown.addOnce(myFireFunction)
```

This will prevent the user from rapidly tapping the screen and calling multiple events on multiple threads.  You can then add the callback to the `onDown` signal once the game has finished processing the first event.

Look up [Phaser's powerful `Signal` Class](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.1/Phaser.Signal.html) and the [Timer Class](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.1/Phaser.Timer.html) and related tutorials to see how to expand on this idea.